# Why does the FormController instantiate models with the ignore_request flag set to true?

Tags: jform, controller

The Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\FormController::getModel method has a default argument for the config argument that sets the `ignore_request` parameter to true. This in turn means that models will not call the `populateState` method.

Why is the `FormController`, the only controller to prevent `populateState` being called? What is the reason that you wouldn't want `populateState` to be called when working with a submitted form?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but I've thought of a reason why it makes sense, so here goes …

Joomla components use `FormController` to handle whenever the (usually admin) user is editing an item and then presses eg `Save` to save the changes. This results in an HTTP POST to the server with the `task` parameter set, and control gets routed to the appropriate controller php file in the component `controllers` directory.

The controller needs to get the form loaded in order to validate the POST data, and this involves going to the component `model` and using it to load the form. During this process the model's `getState` can be called, and hence `populateState`.

However, because Joomla uses the Post/Redirect/Get pattern, this HTTP POST is going to end up with an HTTP redirect. The method `populateState` on the other hand sets up variables which are later used in preparation for outputting data in an HTTP response, and also can involve database queries, eg to get config params. So it's actually doing a lot of work, sometimes involving database queries, for no good reason, as the HTTP response in this case will be a redirect.

Maybe the Joomla team were doing some performance analysis and noticed that there were database queries which were superfluous, tracked them down to `populateState` and then came up with this `ignore_request` flag as a generic solution that didn't involve changing each component.

Have I convinced you ;-) ?